# Laravel5.2 Session use forget() but no work

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I use Laravel5.2 to build a E-commerce platform and get some troubles.When I loginout user state and I use `Session::forget('user')` or `$request->session()->forget('user')`, it works in current page,and I redirect to the login page and `dd(Session::all())` find the session 'user' still exist!!! so I am confused to know what is wrong with it? plz tell me the reason,thanks all.

ps. loginout code

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->session()->has('user')) {
        $is_forgotten = $request->session()->forget('user');
        if ($is_forgotten === null)
            echo json_encode(['result' => 1]);
        exit;
    }
    echo json_encode(['result'=>0,'msg'=>'loginout error']);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Already in laravel has native logout system,why you are using this?

Comment: try to use `\Session::forget('user')` or `session()->forget('user')`

Comment: @Qazi yeah, I just use Session::forget('user') or session()->forget('user') ,it really work in current page , but redirect to the login page find the session user still alive

Comment: @ImtiazPabel yes it is bro. but i just want to use Session to do this, if it can support $_SESSION, i will perfer.

Comment: do one thing, 1st destroy all sessions, the again do a login and logout, check that user session still exists or not?

Comment: @Qazi  use  `return redirect()`  the session had been deleted effectively!!!   so the fact is using `window.location.href=url` no work,should use the method `return redirect()`

Comment: it seems that you doing logout Ajax based ? if yes then `window.location= url` will work

Answer (score 0):

The session doesn't get saved until the response is sent and events/middleware are triggered.

Try doing:

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->session()->has('user')) {
        $is_forgotten = $request->session()->forget('user');
        if ($is_forgotten === null)
            return Response::json(['result' => 1]);
        return '';
    }
    return Response::json(['result'=>0,'msg'=>'loginout error']);
}
```

Or if your using the helpers:

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->session()->has('user')) {
        $is_forgotten = $request->session()->forget('user');
        if ($is_forgotten === null)
            return response()->json(['result' => 1]);
        return '';
    }
    return response()->json(['result'=>0,'msg'=>'loginout error']);
}
```